# Como alterar a largura de uma coluna de uma tabela no Python Docx?

Tags: python, microsoft-word

Como mudar a largura de uma tabela no python docx?
Estou usando: `tabela.columns[1].width = Cm(3.5)`, pretendo mudar a segunda coluna, mas nada acontece.

O código:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm
#Criar do documento word
documento = Document()
#Criando tabela
tabela = documento.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
tabela.style = "Table Grid"
#Escrevendo na primeira linha da tabela
row = tabela.rows[0].cells
row[0].text = "Município"
row[1].text = "Itinerário"
row[2].text = "Turno(s)"
row[3].text = "Tipo de Veículo"
# Mudar a largura da linha
tabela.columns[1].width = Cm(3.5)
#Salvando o documento word
documento.save("Documento.docx")
```

O resultado obtido:
[image: Tabela com todas as colunas iguais]

O resultado desejado:
[image: Tabela com coluna alongada]

Comment: Para que a pergunta atenda à finalidade deste site e possa receber respostas, é importante [edit] a postagem e trocar o código por um [mcve] do trecho com problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Feito, o código está reduzido, todo comentado e rodando, só não tem o resultado desejado.

Comment: Melhorou muito com sua edição. Notei que você só está mexendo em uma coluna. Tentou especificar uma medida maior em `tabela.columns[1].width`? Não conheço essa lib, mas talvez tenha que setar as 4 colunas, de 0 a 3 para fazer algum efeito, seria um bom teste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei em um [site estrangeiro](https://theprogrammingexpert.com/set-widths-table-columns-python-docx/) que a alteração deve ser feita célula por célula:

Então com o código:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm
#Criar do documento word
documento = Document()
tabela = documento.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
tabela.style = "Table Grid"
#Escrevendo na primeira linha da tabela
row = tabela.rows[0].cells
row[0].text = "Município"
row[1].text = "Itinerário"
row[2].text = "Turno(s)"
row[3].text = "Tipo de Veículo"
# Mudar a largura da coluna
tabela.rows[0].cells[1].width = Cm(5)
#Salvando o documento word
documento.save("Documento.docx")
```

Consegui o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para todas as células de uma coluna deve ser feito aplicando um `for` em `tabela.rows[i].cells[1].width = Cm(5)` para todas as linhas da tabela.

Mas ainda desconfio que tenha alguma forma melhor, pois na [biblioteca](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Column.width)  possui esse argumento de largura para colunas.